# Компьютерная версия для сайта

Tags: css3, html5

Как отображать компьютерную версию по умолчанию? Что можно прописать в head?

Comment: А в head есть viewport ?

Comment: Да

name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"

Comment: Удалите его и страница потеряет адаптивность